# Get pseudo-length value in scrlttr2

Tags: lengths, scrlttr2

I am customizing a  `scrlttr2` template.
I'd like to use some pseudo-length values to define other ones.

For example, I defined `\@setplength{firstheadhpos}{2.10cm}` and I'd like to define the pseudo-length`firstfoothpos` equal to `firstheadhpos`.

Of course, I could use `\@setplength{firstfoothpos}{2.10cm}`, but it is not robust. And neither `\@setplength{firstfoothpos}{\value{firstheadhpos}}` nor `\@setplength{firstfoothpos}{\firstheadhpos}` works.

**Question:** How to get the value of a pseudo-length?

Comment: PS: `\@getplength{<pseudo-length>}` is not defined neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you didn't provide a MWE, I only can guess that you are looking for the command `\useplength{name}`. Does this work?:

```
\@setplength{firstfoothpos}{\useplength{firstheadhpos}}
```

Comment: Yes indeed. I didn't add a MWE since I though this was a 'trivial' question... and the fact I couldn't find the right macro also made me too lazy. My bad.